# "There is" or "There are" a man and a woman?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, compound-subjects

> There is a man and a woman standing nearby the drugstore.

or

> There are a man and a woman standing nearby the drugstore.

?

Comment: In existential constructions like this, the dummy pronoun "there" inherits its number agreement properties from the subject it displaces. In this case the displaced subject consists of a coordination of two NPs linked with "and", so it follows that the verb should also be plural (cf. "A man and a woman are / *is standing near the structure"). Informally, however, especially with present tense declaratives with reduced _is_ , many speakers rightly or wrongly always treat "there" as singular.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, according to grammarians, it would have to be the latter, "There are a man and a woman standing *near* [more idiomatic than "nearby"] the drugstore."

The man and the woman *are* standing there. There they are. There *are* a man and a woman near the drugstore.

*But*, you will frequently hear, "There is," in that situation. People say it a lot. It really doesn't even sound wrong to me, and I say it that way myself sometimes.

So if the population says it, is it really incorrect? I say either is acceptable, but only your second option follows the rules of English grammar.

Comment: It's increasingly common to hear native English speakers say things like: **There's several people waiting outside** and **there's all sorts of trouble brewing**. I suspect it's only a matter of time before this construction becomes common currency.