# Plural or singular in "There (is/are) one cinema and two hotels there now."

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The exercise is to pick the correct verb in the following sentences:

> Last year there (was/were) two cinemas and one hotel on Apple street.
>
> There (is/are) one cinema and two hotels there now.

In the first it's definitely "were". What about the second?

Context: this exercise was given to elementary school kids in an English class in a non-English speaking country. The teacher said that the correct answer is "is" becasue the part of the subject immediately following the verb is singular "one cinema". Is this true?

I know that this question is very similar to ["There is" or "There are" a man and a woman?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191109/there-is-or-there-are-a-man-and-a-woman). But I still would like to ask it for this exercise, intentionally constructed to be confusing.

Comment: Yes: generally we would use the rule of **proximity**, whereby the noun nearest to the verb determines the verb-form, singular or plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proximity is important for English speakers. Use the verb that matches the closest noun unless it's an odd circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence should be rewritten as:

> There are two hotels and one cinema there now.